# Why can't I an array in a method outside its class?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, methods, syntax

I have created the array and outside of its class I have created a method to sort the array. It keeps saying it can't find the variable name of the array I made. When I take the method and put it into the same class as the array it works but it defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to achieve, help?

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        System.out.println("Enter a length for the array: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();

        int randomNumbers[] = new int[x];

        for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)

        {
            randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)

        {
            System.out.println(randomNumbers[index]);
        }

    }

    static void sortAscending()

    {
        Arrays.sort(randomNumbers);

        for (int i = 1; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + randomNumbers[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pass `randomNumbers` as a method argument. If you need to return the `array` sorted instead of just printing stuff, `return` it.

Comment: I'm working on a problem that is asking me to write a method sortAscending and one descending, I've created them but how would I return the array instead of printing.

Comment: Terrible code formatting. If you want someone to help you out please put some effort in asking your question properly (formatting etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Since `randomNumbers` is declared in the `main` method, other methods can't access it. There are several ways to make the array accessible from the other method, e.g.:

1. pass as parameter to the method:

   ```
   static void sortAscending(int[] randomNumbers) {
       //...
   }
   ```

   and call `sortAscending` call from `main` like this

   ```
   sortAscending(randomNumbers);
   ```
2. Pass the value through a field. I wouldn't use a static field however, since there's only one of these fields for all instances. But you could make use a instance of your class and store the value in a non-static field:

   ```
   publc class MyClass {

       // declare randomNumbers as field
       private int[] randomNumbers;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           MyClass o = new MyClass();
           o.localMain(args);

           // you could call sortAscending here like this
           o.sortAscending();
       }

       // you don't really need to pass args, since you don't use it
       public void localMain(String[] args) {
           // TODO code application logic here

           System.out.println("Enter a length for the array: ");
           Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
           int x = scan.nextInt();

           // assing new value to field
           randomNumbers = new int[x];

           for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
           {
               randomNumbers[index] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
           }

           for (int index = 0; index < randomNumbers.length; index++)
           {
               System.out.println(randomNumbers[index]);
           }

       }

       void sortAscending()
       {
           Arrays.sort(randomNumbers);

           for (int i = 1; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
               System.out.println("Number: " + randomNumbers[i]);
           }
       }  

   }
   ```